# Concatenate values from a 1:N relationship in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables that have a 1:N relationship. 
I wanna do a query selecting data from the father table and listing all the results of one column in the child table without using cursor.

This is the wrong query (it gives me a different line for each value in the CC table.)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C.NUM_CONTRATO) AS 'Ligação',
       C.NUM_CONTRATO as 'CONTRATOCLIENTE',
       'N' as 'ALTERACAO',
       C.TXT_NOME_CONTRATO as 'RESUMO',
       C.COD_TIPO_CONTRATO as 'CATEGORIA',
       CC.NUM_FORNECEDOR as 'FORNECEDORCLIENTE',
       C.NUM_USUARIO_APROVACAO as 'TAG',
       C.DTH_INICIO_VALIDADE as 'VALIDADE_INICIO',
       C.DTH_TERMINO_VALIDADE as 'VALIDADE_FIM',
       '' as 'COND_PAGTO',
       '' as 'FRETE',
       M.COD_MOEDA as 'MOEDA',
       CASE C.SIT_CONTRATO WHEN 'A' THEN '1' WHEN 'B' THEN '3' END as 'STATUS',
       '' as 'VALOR',
       C.DTH_APROVACAO as 'DATA_DOCUMENTO',
       C.DES_CONTRATO as 'OBSCLI',
       '' as 'FATURAMENTOMINIMO',
       '' as 'COTACAO',
       '' as 'TRANSPORTADORACLIENTE'
  FROM CONTRATO C
  JOIN MOEDA M
    ON C.COD_MOEDA = M.COD_MOEDA
  JOIN CATEGORIA_CONTRATO CC
    ON CC.NUM_CONTRATO = C.NUM_CONTRATO
```

I wish to bring all the CC.NUM_FORNECEDOR from each line in table CONTRATO in just one row.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you want a comma separated list of these values, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: You're right. Thanks, I will try the options given in this question.